# Why am I getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

The code below is a snippet from my entire program. The only things I have defined is the constructor (`head = 0`), the destructor, and a function that is meant to create a linked list with 20 values in it. They are supposed to be random (which I can handle), but I need to fix this seg fault first. HELP!

structure type for node is:

```
struct ListNode
{
    int value;
    ListNode *next;
};
ListNode *head;
```

CODE:

```
void NumberList::buildSortedList(){
   ListNode *newNode;   
   int number = 1;    
   int count = 0;    
   head->value = number;    
   ListNode *p;   
   do{ 
      p = head;       
      while (p->next) { // traverse the list to the end to append new value 
         p = p->next;     
      newNode = new ListNode; 
      newNode->value = number; 
      newNode->next = NULL;       
      p->next = newNode;      
     }         
   }while (count < 19);   
   }
```

Comment: So you defined in your ctor that `head = 0` and then you do `head->value`? Wonder what could have gone wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (p->next) { // traverse the list to the end to append new value 
     p = p->next;

  newNode = new ListNode; 
  newNode->value = number; 
  newNode->next = NULL; 

  p->next = newNode; 

 }
```

should be

```
  while (p->next) { // traverse the list to the end to append new value 
     p = p->next;
  }

  newNode = new ListNode; 
  newNode->value = number; 
  newNode->next = NULL; 

  p->next = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `head` is a global variable, it is initialized to `NULL`. Dereferencing `NULL` is illegal.

You have to assign a pointer to valid buffer to that before dereferencing it.

```
void NumberList::buildSortedList(){

   ListNode *newNode;

   int number = 1; 

   int count = 0; 

   if (head == NULL) head = new ListNode; // add this line
   head->value = number; 

   ListNode *p; 

   do{ 
      p = head; 

      while (p->next) { // traverse the list to the end to append new value 
         p = p->next;
      }  // move this in order not to break the list

      newNode = new ListNode; 
      newNode->value = number; 
      newNode->next = NULL; 

      p->next = newNode; 


   }while (count++ < 19); // add ++ to avoid infinite loop

}
```